# Laravel's "require_if" field value is contained within an array

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

In my controller's "store" (POST) function, I wanted to validate a particular input field. I have a field `listPrice` that is required ONLY if the value of another field, `vendor`, is in an array. The array of vendors would need to be populated from a separate service call. So, my question is two fold:

1. How do I write the validation rule to require `listPrice` if `vendor`'s value is contained within an array and
2. When would I populate the array of vendor's? Would it be inside the `store()` function and run every time that function is called? The validation rules are in a private array of the controller class, so that's only created once I believe, not every time the `store()` function is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.
This would be fairly simple if you could access the $this[data] from laravel's validator, but if you're just using Validator::extend for your custom rule, I don't believe you can. Nor will you be able to access other validation rules from within your rule, which could come in handy here. So the cleanest would probably be to extend the validator class.

```
class CustomValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator {

    public function validateIfInVendorArray($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
    $other = $parameters[0];
    $vendor = $this->data[$other];

    //populate your array from your service call, then check if present
    $vendorArray = your service call or wherever you have it;

    //if in array, return the result of the Validator's validateRequired method, which we can access since it's protected in Validator        
    if (in_array($vendor,$vendorArray))
        return $this->validateRequired($attribute,$value);

    //if it wasn't in the array, return true to pass validation even if it doesn't exist
    return true;
    }
}
```

Just remember to also [register your custom validator resolver](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules)

To use your rule you just pass in the attribute name of the vendors field as a parameter.

2.
I think this depends on where your array is required, and how often.

If it's only required for this validation I would do it inside your custom validation rule, to avoid piling up more work for the controller.

Personally I would move the validation rules to a custom validator class, and then you could have the vendor array as a field of that custom validator. This custom validator class would then be a service for your controller to consume, see https://tutsplus.com/lesson/validation-services/ for a good example.

I haven't tested any of this myself, but I believe it should work! Sorry if it's not the most elegant solution.

Comment: Hi @pfrendly: I am following your suggested solution. It's good but facing one issue. Fox example if i am using it like : 
'field_name' => 'required|if_in_vendor_array:vendor_field'
It is working but
'field_name' => 'if_in_vendor_array:vendor_field'
is not working...what could be the reason?